# Override Float class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created Float class in lib folder:

```
class Float
  def precision(p = 2)
    # Make sure the precision level is actually an integer and > 0
    raise ArgumentError, "#{p} is an invalid precision level. Valid ranges are integers > 0." unless p.class == Fixnum or p < 0
    # Special case for 0 precision so it returns a Fixnum and thus doesn't have a trailing .0
    return self.round if p == 0
    # Standard case
    (self * 10**p).round.to_f / 10**p
  end
end
```

In rspec tests, works. But when the application is running, this error is raised:

```
undefined method `precision' for 5128.5:Float
```

How to make this override work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the [number_with_precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) helper?

Comment: @MichaelKohl, i changed the line for this: `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper.number_with_precision(price, :precision => 2)`, but get the error: `undefined method number_with_precision' for ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper:Module`

Comment: `unless p.class == Fixnum or p < 0` - you might want to refactor that, since negative integers will slip through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby already implements a `round` method for `Float`. There is no need for your implementation.

```
0.12345.round(2) # => 0.12
0.12345.round(3) # => 0.123
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
module MyFloatMod
  def precision(p = 2)
    # Make sure the precision level is actually an integer and > 0
    raise ArgumentError, "#{p} is an invalid precision level. Valid ranges are integers > 0." unless p.class == Fixnum or p < 0
    # Special case for 0 precision so it returns a Fixnum and thus doesn't have a trailing .0
    return self.round if p == 0
    # Standard case
    (self * 10**p).round.to_f / 10**p
  end
end

Float.send(:include, MyFloatMod)
```

EDIT: Almost forgot you also need to make sure this all gets included somewhere during your app's start up.